# не работает проверка на заполнение из dropdown через js

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="rov">
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="sex">Пол:</label>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <FORM name="fsex" method="post" onklick ="ValidSex()">
          <select id="dropdownMenu1" name="sex"  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block"   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
           <option value="disabled"></option>
           <option value="man">Мужчина</option>
           <option value="woman">Женщина</option>
          </select>
            </FORM >
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="display:none;color:green;" aria-hidden="true" id="okSex"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="display:none;color:red;" aria-hidden="true" id="noSex"></span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidSex(form){
            var r = "disabled";
            var mySex = document.fsex.sex;
            var valid = ( document.fsex.sex.options(document.fsex.sex.selectedIndex).value!==r);
            if (valid) {
                document.getElementById('noSex').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('okSex').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById('okName').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('okSex').style.display = 'block';
            }
            return valid;
        };
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: `onklick` - really?

Comment: Что у тебя с кодом? Это страшный сон веб программиста. Быстро учить js )

Comment: а что надо?подскажите

Comment: @АлексейФёдоров, напиши какую проверку оно должно выполнять и я напишу тебе код

Comment: есть 3 значения,

Comment: пусто,м,ж если пусто то появляется красный крест

Comment: если выбрано значение зеленая галка

Comment: проблема что не хочет сверять значение условие не выполняется

Answer (score 1):

Смотри что я набросал, если что, вставляй в свой код

```js
function validSex(e) {
  if(document.form_sex.sex.value !== 'disabled'){
    document.getElementById('sex_valid').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('sex_avalid').style.display='none';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('sex_valid').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('sex_avalid').style.display='block';
  };
}
```

```css
#sex_avalid {color: red;}
#sex_valid {color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span name="sex">Пол:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <form name="form_sex" method="post" onclick="validSex(this)">
        <select name="sex">
          <option value="disabled"></option>
          <option value="max">Мужчина</option>
          <option value="woman">Женщина</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div id="sex_avalid" style="display:none">X</div>
    <div id="sex_valid" style="display:none">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо очень познавательно расписап

Comment: @АлексейФёдоров, отметь ответ как приальный